# How to specify drive when creating solrcloud collection

Tags: solr, solrcloud

When I create a collection via the SOLR Cloud collection API
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Collections+API

How do I specify which drive the collection should be created on?

I'd like to be able to put different collections on different drives.

This is on a Windows Server.

Answer (score 2):

If you check the Collection [CREATE](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Collections+API#CollectionsAPI-CreateaCollecti) section in the [Solr Cloud Collection API](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Collections+API) that you mentioned, you'll see that is possible to specify additional properties in the format

```
property.name=value
```

more specifically if you check the wiki [Defining core.properties](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Defining+core.properties) you'll see that is possible to specify the data directory property

> **dataDir**: The core's data directory (where indexes are stored) as either
>   an absolute pathname, or a path relative to the value of instanceDir. 
>   This is data by default.

in the following way:

```
&property.dataDir=/mydrive/mylocation
```

that wills work with data (the index) directory. The same wiki contains also other properties to specify the locations for other artifacts.